# Es posible usar mas de un dbcontext en entity framework y modificar las cadenas de conexion para ellos?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, context

Estoy creando un proyecto web con Entity Framework  usando Database First.  Ya apliqué la ingeniería inversa para crear los modelos.  Pero necesito acceder a múltiples bases de datos del mismo tipo. Pero de diversos clientes.

Tengo una base de datos madre que me almacena los parámetros encriptados de las cadenas de conexión a las bases de datos de cada uno de los clientes. Por lo cual, el usuario Seleccionaría su grupo empresarial y luego, ingresaría sus credenciales. Entonces, el sistema verificaría  si existe el GE ingresado y  de ser así, obtendría los parámetros de la cadena de conexión a su respectiva base de Datos.

Tengo un dbcontext de la base de Datos Madre, y el dbcontext de La base de Datos Hija.
Necesitaría  en el login poder conectarme al contexto  de la madre,  y armar la cadena de conexión a la base de datos hija por parámetros.  Pasa así poder inyectarlos según sea necesario. He buscado en internet pero no encuentro nada parecido.
Tampoco, he encontrado como modificar el appsettings.json para mantener seguras siempre las conexiones.
Agradecería cualquier ayuda o consejo...

He intentado esto en Program.cs

```
**builder.Services.AddDbContext<SeeposContext>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<AltivaGEContext>();**
```

Pero no comprendo muy bien el tema de  las cadenas de conexión en aplicaciones web

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. POR FAVOR NO GRITES
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Consejos: 1. Entender que poner todo en mayúscula equivale a gritar, esto es ampliamente aceptado por todo lado en internet. 2. Lectura sugerida https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 y muy recomendada para que evites que te den negativos y/o te cierren la pregunta.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).